# Filter on aggregated bucket keys?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Given data model structure like this,

```
{
    Id: 123,
    "string_facet": [
        {
            "name": "make",
            "value": "Audi"
        },
        {
            "name": "carListType",
            "value": "PERSON EU"
        },
        {
            "name": "modelType",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "engineBrand",
            "value": "APT"
        },
        {
            "name": "typeDescription",
            "value": "8D2"
        }
    ],
    "number_facet": [
        {
            "name": "typeNumber",
            "value": 4614
        },
        {
            "name": "serialNumber",
            "value": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "engineSize",
            "value": 18
        },
        {
            "name": "horsePower",
            "value": 125
        },
        {
            "name": "kw",
            "value": 92
        },
        {
            "name": "engineVolume",
            "value": 1781
        },
        {
            "name": "listType",
            "value": 0
        }
    ],
    "dateTime_facet": [
        {
            "name": "fromDate",
            "value": "1999-04-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "name": "toDate",
            "value": "2000-10-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ]    
}
```

I want to get aggregates facet names, and values per name. However, I'm only interested in facets that have specific names, such as: *make* and *engineBrand*. Note that facets are of type nested.

I have tried the following .NEST expression, but it still returns all of the facet names.

```
.Global("global", g => g
    .Aggregations(ag => ag
        .Filter("global_makes", f => f
            .Filter(ff => ff
                .Nested(n => n
                .Path("string_facet")
                .Filter(pf => pf.Term("string_facet.name", "make")))
                )
                .Aggregations(agg => agg
                    .Nested("nested_string_facet", nested => nested
                        .Path("string_facet")
                        .Aggregations(stringFacet => stringFacet
                            .Terms("name", nameAgg => nameAgg.Field("string_facet.name").Size(0)
                                .Aggregations(nameAggNext => nameAggNext
                                    .Terms("value", valueAgg => valueAgg.Field("string_facet.value").Size(0))
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I have a filter within global (to lose scope of a passed in query), and then filter only on string_facet.name which match "make", but results still include all other names as well. How do I filter out aggregation to include only buckets where *name* is "make"?

Answer (score 0):

This helped. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4449

Essentially had to move filter part deeper into aggregation.